How to get specific token info under postBalances and preBalances for getTransaction method
I want to get specific token info transfers for preBalances and postBalances section of SDK's getTransaction method response. As a basis it gives info only in lamports, but can it be used to get specific info about a certain token transfers in their micro-amount instead of lamports?

Take a look at preTokenBalances and postTokenBalances for SPL token balance changes
